# discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel music bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Here's the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get


TOKEN = ""
BOT_PREFIX = "!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@bot.command(pass_context=True, brief="Makes the bot join your channel", aliases=['j', 'jo'])
async def join(ctx):
   channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
   print(channel)
   voice = await channel.connect()
```

When I joined a voice channel, I joined the command, and it printed "music". When I tried again, it printed "music" and sent in error: discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try-except` statement to catch the error, or you can use an if statement to just check if the bot is already connected to a voice channel.

```
try:
    voice = await channel.connect()
except:
    print("Bot already connected")
```

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: Nevermind, it didn't have the connect permissions.